# ArcGIS 10.4.1 export attribute table loses 'shape' column

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, export

I'm running ArcGIS 10.4.1 under Windows 10.

Until a couple of days ago I wasn't having any trouble with exporting attribute tables to csv, editing the resultant files in Excel (Office 365, build 1908) and reloading them. I haven't knowingly changed anything although there has been a MS upgrade to Windows.

Now, every time I download a table it loses the 'shape' attribute with the result that my polygons reload as points. I've tried it with files I've worked with previously and new ones and keep getting the same really frustrating result.

I've also just upgraded to 10.7.1 and the same thing is happening. Short of completely uninstalling and reinstalling I'm stumped about what to do.

Comment: Sorry I should have added this happens if I use the ArcToolbox Table to Excel, Excel to Table option or going through the Attribute table, export route.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional information.

Comment: Incomplete story, How did you export shape to Excel?

Comment: Agree with @FelixIP, an export of the attribute table is that, the attributes, not geometry.